# onFinish method is called before time is up

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have two numberpickers inside an alertdialog and when i press the OK button the countdown starts with the hours and minutes i set, the countdown works great but the onfinish method is called at half time, for example, if i set 1 minute the onfinish method is called when there are 30 seconds remaining.

Here is the code:

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

new CountDownTimer((numberPicker1.getValue()*3600000)+(numberPicker2.getValue()*60000),1000) {

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
Ayuda.this.finish();
String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)-TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)-TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))); 

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tiempo restante "+hms, 1000).show();

}
public void onFinish() {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tiempo terminado ", 1000).show();

Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
}
}.start();
}
```

Comment: Are you sure ? Because I tried your code and its working fine. Maybe value of numberPicker1 and numberPicker2 is getting manipulated before it is inputted in your CountDownTimer.

Comment: I'm completely sure, maybe i should call the Toast in a thread so it performs better.